# Please tell me how to write condition in php class method

Tags: php, class, methods

my code now:

```
if ($condition) {
      $result = ORM::for_table($tableName)
         ->order_by_ACS($columnSort)
         ->findArray();
} else { 
      $result = ORM::for_table($tableName)
         ->order_by_DESC($columnSort)
         ->findArray();
}
```

question how to write like

```
$result = ORM::for_table($tableName)
// if (true) {
            ->order_by_asc($columnSort)
// } else { ->order_by_desc($columnSort) }
            ->findArray();
```

/** nothing. just some comment to post this post) **/

Comment: $result->order_by_asc($columnSort);

Comment: @user2182349  - Call to a member function order_by_desc() on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build method invocations by string identifiers.

```
class TestClass
{
  function test1() { echo 'first method<br>'; }
  function test2() { echo 'second method<br>'; }
}

$test = new TestClass();

for($i = 0; $i<=1 ; $i++)
  $test->{'test' . ($i === 0 ? '1' : '2')}();
```

So your example would become

```
$result = ORM::for_table($tableName)
  ->{ $condition ? 'order_by_asc' : 'order_by_desc' }($columnSort)
  ->findArray()
;
```